# NetBeans IDE is not accepting any input after I run code scanner

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using JDK19 on NetBeans IDE.

After I run the code with scanner the NetBeans IDE is not accepting any input from me, so I could not continue the code "but before I used jcreator and I could input numbers into the console"

[image: Screen shot]

I keep googling and YouTube on how people run the code, and even google how to run code in netbeans so I learn I can right click to run a single code, but the code ran but I could not type in any numbers "integer"

Comment: it's waiting for your input.

Comment: You may need to mouse click on the line in the output window containing "Enter number: " to set focus before entering a number, or did you already do that?

Comment: It seems strange that your **Projects** window is showing _"No Project Open"_ in your screen shot. How did you manage to run your project if it was closed? Also, I copied your code and ran it, and it worked fine for me; this seems to be an issue with the way you are using NetBeans.